# android-how can i get exact number while implement cluster manager in google map in "Android" please give me proper answer if anyone have...?

Tags: android, google-maps, markerclusterer

How Can I get exact number in bucket of cluster manager?

Can anyone give me an example ? how to get exact like 42,35 instead of 20+,50+ etc ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I get the exact number for my clusters. If you have a look at the [advanced example of markerclusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html) you also see the exact number. So please provide some code or more information.

Comment: [advance example of markerclusterer](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/examples/advanced_example.html)  - i think this for  web i want in android........  thanks for reponse... @mxlse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering) of clustering in Google Maps Android API, you will see here on how to [customize the marker cluster](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#custom).

It is stated here that the `ClusterManager` constructor creates a `DefaultClusterRenderer` and you can change the `ClusterRenderer` and the Algorithm using the `setAlgorithm(Algorithm<T> algorithm)` and `setRenderer(ClusterRenderer<T> view)` methods of ClusterManager.

The `DefaultClusterRenderer` provides a base to start from, and to override this defaults, you need to subclass the `DefaultClusterRenderer`.

For more information, you can check this [thread](http://www.devsplanet.com/question/36137333) and this [sample code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) on how to customize the marker cluster.

Comment: yes , this [sample code](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java) work **but sometimes it does'nt** give proper exact numer.....  mostly when map maximum zoom out ..........thanks..- @KENdi

Comment: answer should be updated with new links for an example, otherwise yes this is a vague starting point that can help

Answer (score 2):

> May be this is not the best answer but it has been work for me.

```
public class CustomClusterClass extends DefaultClusterRenderer<Data> {

public CustomClusterClass(Context context, MapboxMap map,
                              ClusterManagerPlugin<Data> clusterManagerPlugin) {
        super(context, map, clusterManagerPlugin);
    }

 @Override
    protected String getClusterText(int bucket) {
        return super.getClusterText(bucket).replace("+", "");
    }

    @Override
    protected int getBucket(Cluster<Data> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize DefaultClusterRenderer class.

//to get the exact count of map clustering

```
protected int getBucket(Cluster<T> cluster) {
    int size = cluster.getSize();
    return size;
}
```

refer this link https://github.com/MadhuProjectWorks/GoogleMapClustering

Answer (score 0):

*For anyone else visiting later:*

As far as my experience with Android is concerned, you will need to use a custom cluster if you want to display the exact number of items in a cluster. I too have been searching for a way to show the exact number **while using the default cluster marker / circle**.

So, just as everyone is pointing out, check out the [sample code here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/marker-clustering.). You will then need to use the below code to get the exact cluster item count:

```
override fun onBeforeClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<MyClusterItem>?, markerOptions: MarkerOptions?){
    //... create your view
    val clusterSize = cluster?.items?.size
    //user clusterSize on your custom view
}
```

Once again, be patient and go through the code in the link and create your own view and eventually you will be using the cluster size and you want it to be.